# Returning results based on combinations of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I wonder if this is even possible in T-SQL.

The idea is to "not" return rows like row 1 and row 4 if the combination of rows 2 and 3 / rows 5 and 6 exist.

```
declare @table table
(
 A int,
 B char(2),
 C char(2),
 D char(2)
)

insert into @table
select 2, 'A1', 'B1', NULL  -- row 1
union
select 2, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'  -- row 2 and row 3 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                       
select 3, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'   
union
select 2, 'A2', 'B2', NULL  -- row 4
union
select 2, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'  -- row 5 and row 6 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                     
select 3, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'
```

Anyone who wants to have a go at this?
Thank you
Best Regards
Steve

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the question without any reference to SQL. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D FROM @table 
WHERE 
A IS NOT NULL AND 
B IS NOT NULL AND 
C IS NOT NULL AND 
D IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D FROM @table 
WHERE 
D IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
declare @table table
(
 ID INT ,
 A int,
 B char(2),
 C char(2),
 D char(2)
)

insert into @table
select 1, 2, 'A1', 'B1', NULL  -- row 1
union
select 2, 2, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'  -- row 2 and row 3 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                       
select 3, 3, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'   
union
select 4, 2, 'A2', 'B2', NULL  -- row 4
union
select 5, 2, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'  -- row 5 and row 6 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                     
select 6, 3, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'

SELECT *
FROM @table t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @table t1 WHERE t.id IN (t1.id + 1, t1.id + 2) 
      AND t.d IS NULL )
```

Comment: This is what got me what I wanted. Many thanks!

Comment: @SteveVerschaeve , would you be so kind to mark my response as accepted? I'm just starting to participate in stackoverflow and it seems that I need few more points to do some further activities :)

Comment: Hi Luis, I wish I could. I need to have a min of 15 points before I can up vote. I'll come back later when I have enough points. Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 2):

`NOT EXISTS` is the way to go:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D from @table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM @table t2
    WHERE t1.A < t2.A 
    AND COALESCE(t1.B,'')=COALESCE(t2.B,'') 
    AND COALESCE(t1.C,'')=COALESCE(t2.C,'') 
    AND COALESCE(t1.D,'')=COALESCE(t2.D,'') 
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16657/0)

The `COALESCE`-trick is to compare two null values. Otherwise `null=null` would return `null` and equal rows with null values would be included.

Comment: null=null evaluates to null. In this particular case that COALESCE trick will be fine, but it shouldn't be used in general.

Comment: @DaveK: Edited my answer to clarify that. You can also use `AND ( (t1.B IS NULL AND  t2.B IS NULL) OR (t1.B IS NOT NULL AND  t2.B IS NOT NULL AND t1.B=t2.B ) )` and so on. But `COALESCE` is easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can get this by filtering records separately using aggregation and ordering of tables. I believe, you want to eliminate those rows which are followed by rows having combinations...
If so, below one might work...

```
declare @table table
(
 A int,
 B char(2),
 C char(2),
 D char(2)
)

insert into @table
select 2, 'A1', 'B1', NULL  -- row 1
union
select 2, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'  -- row 2 and row 3 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                       
select 3, 'A1', 'B1', 'C1'   
union
select 2, 'A2', 'B2', NULL  -- row 4
union
select 2, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'  -- row 5 and row 6 is a combination (values are equal) 
union                     
select 3, 'A2', 'B2', 'C2'   


SELECT 
T.* 
FROM 
@table T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    T1.* 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B,C,D) As RowNumber, 
        MIN(A) AS A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        COUNT(1) Cnt 
        FROM @TABLE
        GROUP BY B,C,D
    ) T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B,C,D) As RowNumber, 
        MIN(A) AS A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        COUNT(1) Cnt 
        FROM @TABLE
        GROUP BY B,C,D
    ) T2 ON T2.RowNumber = T1.RowNumber + 1
    WHERE ISNULL(T2.Cnt,0) <= 1
) NonPostDuplicateRows
ON T.B = NonPostDuplicateRows.B
AND T.C = NonPostDuplicateRows.C
AND T.D = NonPostDuplicateRows.D
```